# How can replace this using sed?

Tags: sed

I'm using OS X, want to replace

```
[self.lang getAppLanguageString:@"foo bar"]
```

to

```
LocalizedString(@"foo bar", nil)
```

I use sed like the below:

```
sed -i '' s/[self\.lang getAppLanguageString:@"([a-zA-Z]+)"]/LocalizedString(@"\1", nil)/g somefile
```

but not work, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already escaped `.` in the pattern, but also need to escape `[` and `]`.

Try:

```
sed -i 's/\[self\.lang getAppLanguageString:@\("[^"]*"\)\]/LocalizedString(@\1, nil)/' somefile
```